# Finding substring in list of strings, return index

Tags: python

I've got a list of strings dumped by `readlines()` and I want to find the index of the first line that includes a substring, or the last line.

This works, but seems clunky:

```
fooIndex=listOfStrings.index((next((x for x in listOfStrings if "foo" in x),listOfStrings[-1])))
```

There has to be a better way than searching twice, but I can't find it.

Comment: Are you sure you need the index? It seems to me the most efficient way would be to loop over the file contents directly (do **not** call readlines) and stop/return when you see the line with the text you want.

Comment: You could use `enumerate` when iterating to get the index of each line.

Comment: I'm slicing up blocks of data, so I'd think it's more efficient to pass an index-sliced sublist to the function containing `numpy.genfromtxt` especially since I can't get that to stop throwing Value errors without a clean data  block (another question I guess I should ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a good (i.e. readable) one-line solution for this. Alternatively to @eugene's loop, you could also use a `try/except`.

```
def get_index(list_of_strings, substring):
    try:
        return next(i for i, e in enumerate(list_of_strings) if substring in e)
    except StopIteration:
        return len(list_of_strings) - 1
```

The code is a little longer, but IMHO the intent is very clear: Try to get the next index that contains the substring, or the length of the list minus one.

---

Update: In fact, there *is* a good (well, somewhat okay-ish) one-liner, and you almost had it, using the `default` parameter of `next`, but instead of using the last element itself as default, and then calling `index`, just put the index itself and combine with `enumerate`:

```
next((i for i, e in enumerate(list_of_strings) if substring in e), 
     len(list_of_strings) - 1)
```

Comment: That second one is more or less what I was looking for, although since I'm going to use the indexes to slice the list, I don't even need the `len(list_of_strings)`, I can just set the default to `-1`: <br/>                        `next((i for i, e in enumerate(list_of_strings) if substring in e),  - 1)`

Comment: @DanielForsman Yes, for slicing (and for pretty much every other purpose) the two are interchangeable. Be aware, though, that slicing to `[...:-1]` will _exclude_ the last element. Not sure if you want that.

Comment: No I don't!  Thanks.

Comment: @DanielForsman So, you want to use that for slicing, and the slice should go up to and including the first element with the substring, or the entire list?

Comment: Yes, although I'm doing two slices usually.  One looking for the header of a specific data block, and one looking for the end of that block.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate) in a function would be both more readable and efficient:

```
def get_index(strings, substr):
    for idx, string in enumerate(strings):
        if substr in string:
            break
    return idx
```

Note that you don't need to call `.readlines()` on a file object to iterate over the lines — just use it as an iterable.